# Send a tcp/ip command

Tags: vb.net, sockets, telnet

I am trying to send a string to a card coder to set a card.

If I send the message via tcp/ip using a specific software, like Putty, the log file of PMS (card software) registers the transaction.

I am trying to send the string via VB.Net, but `TcpClient` does not answer,  and the log file of the PMS does not register anything.

Any suggestions?

This is the code I use:

```vb
Public Function invia_stringa_tcpip() As String
  Dim rr As String
  ' var  ind_tcpip porta_tcpip, stri stringa da inviare
  ind_tcpip = "192.168.1.3"
  porta_tcpip = 3015
  stri = "CCA;EA1;GR101;CO201803021200;AM1;"
  Dim telnetclient As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient()
  telnetclient.Connect(ind_tcpip, porta_tcpip)
  Dim byt_to_send() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stri)
  telnetclient.Client.Send(byt_to_send, 0, byt_to_send.Length, SocketFlags.None)

  If telnetclient.Client.Available < 0 Then 'controlla se il client tcp risponde
    Dim byt_to_receive(telnetclient.Available - 1) As Byte
    telnetclient.Client.Receive(byt_to_receive, 0, byt_to_receive.Length, SocketFlags.None)
    rr = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byt_to_receive)
    Return rr
  End If

End Function
```

Comment: Does the port you are connecting to use the *actual* Telnet protocol?  If so, your code doesn't.  Or does the port use just plain ASCII commands only?  Also, are you expected to send a terminator at the end of the string, such as a line break? If so, you are not sending one. How does the receiver know when you have finished sending the whole command? What does its documentation actually say about the protocol you need to use to communicate with it?

Comment: Hi Remy sorry I did not explain my self well

Comment: The protocol is tcp ip through port 3015. I used the telnet software to check if it works. The receiver expects a string I don't think it's necessary a terminator. As you see I am new to this.

Comment: Telnet uses a line break as a string terminator, so if it works via Telnet you should try to reproduce the same behaviour in your code. Change your string to: `stri = "CCA;EA1;GR101;CO201803021200;AM1;" & Environment.NewLine` and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you Vincent, it works